# Not able to load packages after OSX update

Tags: r

**Edit:** I partially fixed this by setting a new library and installing all packages again to the new location.

I have OSX v10.13.6 and R 3.5. After the most recent OSX update, R does not seem to locate any of my installed packages, and they do not appear in RStudio either. E.g. trying to load `ggplot2` which is installed under the same location as `.libPaths()`:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library"
> list.files("/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library")
  [1] "abind"                "acepack"              "airway"               "annotate"             "AnnotationDbi"       
....
 [96] "ggplot2"              "git2r"                "glue"                 "GO.db"                "GOstats"             
> library(ggplot2)
Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
> library("ggplot2", lib.loc=.libPaths())
Error in library("ggplot2", lib.loc = .libPaths()) : 
  there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
```